# Register password strength meter not working in Magento 2.2.5 CE

Tags: magento-2.2.5, form-validation, password, bug

I have a fresh installation of `Magento 2.2.5 CE` & tried to create new user on frontend when we type password like `Password1`

strangely strength meter not showing like weak, strong, very strong its simply say no password but passed the password validation.

**Validation Rule:**

```
<div class="field password required">
    <label for="password" class="label"><span>Password</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="Password" class="input-text valid" data-password-min-length="8" data-password-min-character-sets="3" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true"><div for="password" generated="true" class="mage-error" id="password-error" style="display: none;">Minimum of different classes of characters in password is 3. Classes of characters: Lower Case, Upper Case, Digits, Special Characters.</div>
        <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite" class="password-none">
            <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                Password Strength:
                <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">No Password</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Image:**
[image]

**Looking forward to:**

1) is this Magento bug? if yes share the bug link.

2) need workaround for this? or point out to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19071) issue.

And [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/c8ead232063d3f4406cb77950643042643952609) is the commit that probably fixes your problem.

You need to override **app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/password-strength-indicator.js**, and change line 86 to:

```
displayScore = isValid && zxcvbnScore > 0 ? zxcvbnScore : 1;
```

See detailed info the aforementioned issue.

Comment: Seems this code change is already there in Magento-2.3

Comment: In my case, my other JavaScript files were creating issues.